# SWIFT: Controlling a view on another users device

Tags: swift, multiple-users

This is a simple question on a (probably) complicated topic.

I'm in the process of trying to build an app in which multiple users are invited into a session by a single user.

If they accept, I would like the session admin/host's device to control the views on the devices of all the users in that session.

I have searched high and low, Google, StackOverflow, Treehouse etc. but whenever I suggest multiple users or type the question as I have here I get responses that demonstrate how to make an app capable of supporting multiple users on one device, or similar.

The question is simply: is what I want to do possible? Is it safe? Does anyone have a resource that would get me started in learning about how to code this scenario.

Thanks in advance,
Kyle.

Comment: Yeah its possible, but its not a simple answer. I would suggest maybe taking a look at something like this https://realm.io the demo on the first page will give you a hint on what you can do.

Comment: FTR you'd probably just use PubNub for this (even easier for presence than Realm - which is fantastic) - the problem is, **it will first take seven years for the OP to become a competent, fast, mobile programmer**, and then after that it will take 15 minutes to make such an app (using PubNub).

Comment: Completely forgot about PubNub, awesome suggestion @Fattie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy as pie** - you use PubNub for exactly that.

demo similar to your problem:

https://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/codoodler/

(That demo is in-browser, but it's equally easy to do inside an app - assuming you're an experienced app developer of course!)

more demos:

https://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/

I can tell you're new at mobile development. Do understand that:

A) In general programming is extremely difficult. Programming mobiles in particular ***has a lot of fussy knowledge needed*** as well as broad general engineering skills.

B) We really live in the "age of BAAS" - "platforms" such as PubNub, FireBase, Parse, Realm, Couchbase and so on.  (These days you can't really be an "app programmer" .... you can't get a job "programming an iPhone".  You get a job doing Firebase development, happening to be on iPhone - you know?)

Comment: I'm fairly new to it but I'm familiar with Parse and so on. I'm not trying to do it all with the power of the iPhone, I've embraced the internet.

I'm definitely not experienced, and I think this will be significantly more than 15 minutes work as you suggested beneath but I'm working on my own idea whilst learning because it's more fun and more useful to use your brain to get around the difficulties than to copy other people's code!

It'll take me a while, but with persistence and the kind assistance of the community I'll get there.

Thanks for the tip. 
Happy coding!

Comment: enjoy yourself.  it will take you some time to get your head around Presence services but then you'll see how easy it is.  Another good one like pubnub is ably.io, I have not used them yet. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe Apple has documentation on this very topic:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity

The trickier part will be how do you send back and forth data that allows the host to "control" the views of the other devices.  If by "control" you want to let the host control things that are outside of your app (like a screen share) I don't believe that will be possible.

Comment: Bonjour!  :)  (Joke for old people.)  That's just if you want to do "local" multiplayer gaming.  (For anyone under about 70 years old who will have no clue what I'm talking about ..... I can't even be bothered explaining what that was.)  All you do these days, to do what the OP describes, is this https://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/codoodler/, it's 15 minutes work thanks to presence platforms.  Nothing to it.  BUT that's if you're an experienced engineer.

Comment: Hey!  I'm not 'old'!

Comment: LOL - me neither  :)

Comment: Thanks for the keyword 'multipeer connectivity', too, Scott.